# How do I display an image on an html 5 video element if and only if the video element is only outputting audio?

Tags: javascript, html, video, webrtc

I have a video element that is either displaying both video and audio or just audio through a stream.  I need to display a temporary image if it is only outputting audio.  Does the "poster" attribute for a video element work?  Or does that only display before the video has started playing?

Is there anyway to detect if a video element is only outputting audio?

Comment: some browsers let you feed a canvas tag from a video tag. if you did that for three frames, and resized the canvas to 1px x 1px, and sumed the RGB data for each of the three pixels, and they were all the same, the video contains only audio.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions:

- Use `getVideoTracks()` to check if the stream has video.
- Check the `videoHeight` of the video: if it's zero, there's no video.